# Intellij go to error shortcut that selects text?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I know the shortcuts to navigate between errors in IntelliJ (F2/shift + F2). But they don't select the text. They just put the cursor at the beginning.

In Eclipse they select it. I like this because then I just have to start typing, or paste something to correct it - which is very useful when there are a lot of errors with the same pattern. Is there a way to reproduce this functionality in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA, as the number of cases where fixing an error requires replacing some expression is actually far from 100%. You can get similar results by pressing Ctrl+W (Select Word) shortcut after being navigated to an error.

Comment: It's not necessary that it's 100%. Deselecting a preselected block is easier (1 key) than selecting it (CTRL+W in the best case). Also, it could be a different shortcut.